# Can't hande Jquery .mouseout

Tags: jquery, tabs, opera, mouseover, mouseout

I'm making an animation with .mouseover and .mouseout and with .hover, but in the two methods, when I change the tab of my opera browser and get back to the page the mouseout function (and the second function from .hover), are executed again:

```
$("#getBtn")
    .mouseover(function(){
        $("#menuTabLogo").css("background-image","url(img/over.gif)");
    })
    .mouseout(function(){
        $("#menuTabLogo").css("background-image","url(img/normal.gif");
    });     

$("#ubBackground").hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().css("background-image","url(img/userBoxMouseOver.gif)");
}, function(){
    $(this).stop().css("background-image","url(img/userBoxMouseOut.gif)");
});
```

So that's simply my code, maybe it's not the best programming decision, but I'm new to JQuery and that works for me (without this 'bug'). So any decisions are welcomed. :)

Comment: Do you mean mouseout is triggered when you are not moving the mouse over the browser window? And how do you know?

Comment: Could you paste some code and set up a demo on http://jsfiddle.net/ ?